# React native modal vs react-navigation modal, which is more performant?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-modal

As of now, I am using React native modal right now. My modal contains some lightweight animation inside it. Now some questions are poking for a while. Should I use react native Modal, which is built-in, or Should I use react-navigation full screen modal? Which is mode performant? It may vary from situation to situation, but where should I use the react-native modal and react-navigation Modal? Which is more performant?

Answer (score 3):

React navigation modal creates a modal as separate screen while React native modal is a component.

I’ve had cases where my modal doesn’t display over all screens when using react native modal.

But using React navigation Modal approach, you are sure it displays it over all screens.

A modal is like a popup — but in react navigation, it's not part of your primary navigation flow. This can also be a problem in some cases.

React native modal is lighter though, it’s just a component.

Answer (score 1):

Modals usually work with performance. I usually use this and I haven't had any performance issues.

https://github.com/react-native-modal/react-native-modal